# Appboy SDK iOS, the unreadCardCountForCategories delegate doesn't gives count for an updated card

Tags: ios, objective-c, badge, appboy, braze

I have integrated the Appboy News feed in my iOS application. I fetch the badge count for the unread number of cards through the unreadCardCountForCategories delegate provided by the SDK. But the count returned by the delegate **doesn't refresh if I update an already existing (read/unread) card from the Appboy dashboard**. Here is the code I use:

```objectivec
[[Appboy sharedInstance] requestFeedRefresh];


[[AppBoyHandler appboySharedInstance].feedController unreadCardCountForCategories:ABKCardCategoryAll]];
```

Any help is appreciated !!

Comment: @d-_-b Now that the [appboy] and [braze] tags are setup, it would have been better to make [appboy] an alias for [braze] instead of having both tags on all of the questions.

Comment: @HangarRash I don't have access to do that. Feel free to make those changes yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Appboy marks unread feed cards as read when a user views the card in the application's News Feed. If you aren't interacting with the News Feed and viewing previously unread cards in between calls to `requestFeedRefresh`, the count returned from `unreadCardCountForCategories` is expected to return the same value.

Please let us know if the above isn't the case, and you're seeing `unreadCardCountForCategories` returning the same value, even after viewing previously unread cards on the News Feed.

Comment: I am following the below cases and in both cases the unread count does not refresh:
1. Create a new news feed from dashboard< read it in the app<now update the feed from the dashboard<the unread count remains zero.
2. Create a new news feed from dashboard< do not read it in the app<now update the feed from the dashboard<the unread count remains 1.

I am refreshing the count in my viewdidappear and also everytime the screen scrolls